# Configure Log4J2 with a System property to use a URL

Tags: log4j2, system-properties

Log4j2 accepts:
    -Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml

@see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html

But we used to be able to use a real URL like http://host/configuration.xml.

Is there a way to achieve this or has it been removed forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Dlog4j.configurationFile` actually accepts URLs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to raise a feature request for this on the log4j2 Jira issue tracker.